# What webpage sent the form?

Tags: php, html, forms

Is it possible to retrieve the infomation about the webpage that sent a form to another webpage? I'm developing a simple page that gives the user the option to send forms to other pages and they can configure the form as they want.

It works in this way: the user puts the input fields they want from my page, then a new page showing the full form is displayed and there they can submit it to the new page.

So I'd basically like to know if there's any way (through php or other languages) to retrieve information about where the form comes from. It's obvious that they can retrieve the user IP, but can they also retrieve information about my page? If so, how would they do it? I've tried to find it online, but I couln't find anything at all.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only piece of information you have (provided that you can't control the sending web page to add fields) is the `HTTP Referer` header. It can be omitted or forged, but it's all you've got.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` superglobal.  Note that this is set by the browser, so it may not always be accurate.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking how to rebuild all the form objects from your HTTP Post or GET, there isn't really a way to. All you can do is assume there is a form with a name and value pair, but to figure out if it came from a text input or a checkbox or radio, etc... there isn't a way. If you have control over the initial page, then you can add more information to what is being posted, such as to each form element, add a type.

```
<input type="text" name="first".../>
<input type="hidden" name="first_type" value="input_text" />
```

Comment: I actually didn't think about if the receiver would check that, I was going to display a warning saying that checkboxes needed a 0 or a 1. I had that in mind already, I'd let the user choose the "name", "value" and "type" (3 inputs) for each form input.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP Referer header should contain the URL the browser was using to access the form. How you retrieve it from PHP, I am not certain. But I think you should be fine knowing that such a header exists.